# Pasar variables de un formulario a un documento MS Word con PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo un problema a la hora de llenar el formulario: se pasa toda la información bien a la base de datos y al igual se descarga el documento pero no se pasan las variables. Las variables coinciden con el formulario el documento y con la base de datos pero nada de nada. Ya instalé todas las dependencia como phpword. Soy nuevo en php espero su ayuda. Ya solo me falta eso para terminar mi proyecto de residencia :)

Aquí está mi código de generar el documento

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php'; // Carga el autoloader de Composer

use PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor;

function descargaComite($nombre, $asunto, $n_telefono, $semestre, $correo_electronico, $n_control, $solicito, $motivo, $razon) {
   
    

    // Ruta de la plantilla del documento .docx
    $plantilla = 'ANEXO XLII. SOLICITUD COMITE.docx';

    // Crear un nuevo procesador de plantillas con la plantilla existente
    $templateProcessor = new TemplateProcessor($plantilla);

    // Reemplazar las variables en la plantilla con los datos del formulario
    $templateProcessor->setValue('NOMBRE', $nombre);
    $templateProcessor->setValue('ASUNTO', $asunto);
    $templateProcessor->setValue('N_TELEFONO', $n_telefono);
    $templateProcessor->setValue('SEMESTRE', $semestre);
    $templateProcessor->setValue('CORREO_ELECTRONICO', $correo_electronico);
    $templateProcessor->setValue('N_CONTROL', $n_control);
    $templateProcessor->setValue('SOLICITO', $solicito);
    $templateProcessor->setValue('MOTIVO', $motivo);
    $templateProcessor->setValue('RAZON', $razon);

    // Guardar el documento temporalmente
    $tempFilePath = 'documento_generado.docx';
    $templateProcessor->saveAs($tempFilePath);

    // Establecer las cabeceras para la descarga
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="documento_generado.docx"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($tempFilePath));

    // Enviar el archivo
    readfile($tempFilePath);

    // Eliminar el archivo temporal después de enviarlo
    unlink($tempFilePath);
}

// Llamar a la función pasando los datos necesarios
descargaComite($nombre, $asunto, $n_telefono, $semestre, $correo_electronico, $n_control, $solicito, $motivo, $razon);
$conn->close();

?>
```

He intentado de todo

Comment: Hola Edgar, ¿podrías compartir un ejemplo del archivo `ANEXO XLII. SOLICITUD COMITE.docx`? Es más que nada para ver como has definido los `search-patterns`

Comment: te funciona con otras plantillas de Word? si es así, el problema está en esta plantilla. Sino, el problema podría estar en tu código. Simplifica plantilla y código para usar un único campo, comprueba los nombres tanto en el código como en la plantilla y prueba de nuevo.

Comment: Las plantillas de Word tienen extensión dotx, estás dando como nombre de plantilla un documento docx, tal vez el processor esté fallando por la estructura del documento esperado.